# If email displays errors then capture error in text file

Tags: powershell

How do i output the error into a text file if I'm not allowed to enable "set-executionpolicy unrestricted"

I'm writing a code to output the error in a text file if the email displays errors/doesn't send out. The only time the error that will appear that I can think of is the smtpserver won't work. I tried the following but it wont write the code to the text file.

```
try {
Send-MailMessage -From 'mail@yahoo.com' -To 'mail22@yahoo.com' -Subject 'Test mail' -SmtpServer 'smtp.abc.applemain.con'
# 1/0
}
catch {
$_.Exception.Message | Out-File -FilePath C:\output.txt #-append
"[$($_.Exception.GetType().FullName)]" | Out-File -FilePath C:\output.txt #-append
}
pause
```

Comment: the `try/catch` structure REQUIRES a "terminating" error. most errors in PoSh are not terminating ... so you usually need to force the targeted command to make errors into terminating ones. take a look at the `-ErrorAction` parameter and the `$ErrorActionPreference` variable.

Comment: @lee_dailey Thanks for the response. it looks like the parameter/variable you mentioned are used to either stop or let the posh script continue. i'm not sure how it's going to help me output the error into a text file.

Comment: you are welcome. [*grin*] ///// the `try/catch` structure REQUIRES a terminating error ... **_and most errors in powershell are not terminating._** that means you must FORCE other errors to be terminating. ///// also, in this case `terminating` does not mean "stop the  script" ... it means stop running things at this point and exit whatever is going on. **_when done inside a `try/catch`, that forces things to go to the `catch` block._**

Comment: references for above ... Terminating Errors - PowerShell | Microsoft Docs — https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/scripting/developer/cmdlet/terminating-errors?view=powershell-7.2 ///// Everything you wanted to know about exceptions - PowerShell | Microsoft Docs — https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/scripting/learn/deep-dives/everything-about-exceptions?view=powershell-7.2

Answer (score 0):

I fixed it.

```
try {
Send-MailMessage -From 'mail@yahoo.com' -To 'mail22@yahoo.com' -Subject 'Test mail' -SmtpServer 'smtp.abc.applemain.con'
}
catch {
$_.Exception.Message | Out-File -FilePath C:\output.txt
}
```

Comment: I took a nap, woke up and looked at my code again. It looks like the problem was that I had to enable Set-ExecutionPolicy unrestricted. Cleaned the code a little bit and it worked. The output file is created and the content is "The remote name could not be resolved: 'msxpsmtp.wcbbc.wcbmain.con" which is the result i was expecting.

Comment: Add `-ErrorAction Stop` to the `Send-MailMessage` line to also catch non-terminating errors

Comment: I have a new dilemma. how do i capture the error into a text file if we can't enable "set-executionpolicy unrestricted" I will update the question.

Comment: I don't know what you mean, because in your previous comment you say _"The output file is created"_.. So it seems to me you can write a file.

Comment: what do you mean by cannot set execution policy ? you can execute powershell as an admin and you cant set it because of GPOs or you are not an admin ?

Comment: @CFou, I'm not the admin.

Comment: @Theo the file is  not created  unless i set the executionpolicy to unrestricted.

Comment: You cannot set restriction policy if powershell execution is not elevated but you can try to run it like this from a cmd line : `powerhsell -ExecutionPolicy ByPass -Command { <your commands there> }`  or  `powerhsell -ExecutionPolicy ByPass -File someScript.ps1`

Comment: @cfou did not work unfortunately.

Comment: @mustfirst I don't understand why this is not working and more, why you need to disable execution policy. I think you don't read @Theo's comment. `Send-MailMessage` line have to finish by `-ErrorAction Stop`, like this : `Send-MailMessage -From "mail@yahoo.com" -To "mail22@yahoo.com" -Subject "Test mail" -SmtpServer "smtp.abc.applemain.con" -ErrorAction Stop`. Errors produced by `Send-MailMessage` are not terminating errors, so will not enter in the `catch` block